# Change Saving-Path - Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

I´m trying to save a file, which I create with the "open" function.
Well I tried nearly everything to change the directory, but nothing works. The file gets always saved in the folder of my file, which I read in before.

```
 file = open(fname[0] + ft, 'w')
 file.write("Test")
 file.close()
```

So this is it simple, but what do I have to add, to change the path of creation?

The File Dialog in a individual Function:

```
global fname
fname = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(None, 'Please choose your File.',"C:\\Program Files", "Text-Files(*.txt)")
```

And the File Typ ( in a individual Function too) I set the file type by ticking a check box and ft will set to .py or .pyw

```
if self.exec_py.isChecked() == True:
  global ft
  ft = ".py"
```

I should have mentioned that I already tried os.path.join and os.chdir, but the file will get printed in the file anyway. Any solutions or approaches how to fix it? Here is how i tried it:

```
tmppath = "C:/temp"
tmp = os.path.join(tmppath,fname[0]+ft)
file = open(tmp, 'w')
```

Comment: Did you try that last little snippet as a standalone script?  It should work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a little short on details, but I am guessing that `fname` is the tuple returned by `QFileDialog`, and so `fname[0]` is the *absolute path* of the original file. So if you display `fname[0]`, you will see something like this:

```
>>> fname[0]
'C:\\myfolder\\file.txt'
```

Now look what happens when you try to use that with `os.path.join`:

```
>>> tmppath = 'C:\\temp'
>>> os.path.join(tmppath, fname[0])
'C:\\myfolder\\file.txt'
```

Nothing! Conclusion: attempting to join two **absolute** paths will simply return the original path unchanged. What you need to do instead is take the *basename* of the original path, and join it to the *folder* where you want to save it:

```
>>> basename = os.path.basename(fname[0])
>>> basename
'file.txt'
>>> os.path.join(tmppath, basename)
'C:\\tmp\\file.txt'
```

Now you can use this new path to save your file in the right place.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the full filepath

```
with open(r'C:\entire\path\to\file.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('test')
```

If you just provide a file name without a path, it will use the current working directory, **which isn't necessarily the directory where the python script your running is located**.  It will be the directory where you launched the script from.

```
C:\Users\admin> python C:\path\to\my_script.py
```

In this instance, the current working directory is `C:\Users\admin`, not `C:\path\to`.